# What is the point of using a 2d TextureRegion array?

Tags: java, textures, libgdx, sprite

So the question is exactly what the subject header says. I'm following a libdgx tutorial and the guy is putting a 1d textureRegion array into a 2d textureRegion array. The line of code is as follows:

```
TextureRegion[][] temp = TextureRegion.split(sheet, 16, 16);
```

Currently, my take on it is this: A `Texture` is just an image. While a `sprite` is rectangular entity with a texture mapped to it. And a `TextureRegion[][]` takes an entire spriteSheet and can locate a specific sprite you want to use.

So effectively, he's created a way for us to make sprites just off the 2d textureRegion array? Just need clarification, thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the API? "Helper function to create tiles out of the given Texture starting from the top left corner going to the left and ending at the bottom right corner. Only complete tiles will be returned so if the texture's width or height are not a multiple of the tile width and height not all of the texture will be used."
(http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html#split(com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture, int, int))

Comment: Yeah, I have from hovering over it with eclipse, I was just trying to verify that all of that is saying what I said above, since in the tutorial there was no explanation given. But, I think I follow. 

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the point of using a 2d TextureRegion array?

It is easier if your TextureRegions are well ordered and same size. So instead of this:

```
TextureRegion t1 = new TextureRegion(atlas, x, y, w, h);
TextureRegion t2 = new TextureRegion(atlas, x, y, w, h);
TextureRegion t3 = new TextureRegion(atlas, x, y, w, h);
...
```

You would have this:

```
TextureRegion[][] ts = TextureRegion.split(atlas, w, h);
TextureRegion t1 = ts[0][0];
TextureRegion t2 = ts[0][1];
...
```

You don't put the positions yourself.